# If EventConstructor is not a constructor, how should I create the event?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm following `MDN` guide and trying to create an event:

[MDN guide for creating events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```
var jGp = new Object();
...
jGp.evt = new Object();
jGp.evt.erro = new Event("jGp_evtErro");
```

The error is (Safari):

```
TypeError: '[object EventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Event("jGp_evtErro")')
```

Also to use `document.createEvent` seams to be deprecated (as `MDN` says), so how should I create my event?

Comment: What version f Safari are you using and what platform are you on? It works fine for me.

Comment: Safari 5.1.10 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this too on Safari, I used a try/catch statement in order to use the non-deprecated constructor whenever possible, but fail into the old way if necessary.

```
jGp.evt = new Object();
try {
  jGp.evt.erro = new Event("jGp_evtErro");
}
catch (e) {
  jGp.evt.erro = document.createEvent('Event');
  jGp.evt.erro.initEvent("jGp_evtErro", true, true);
}
```